# Check laravel websocket on server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

Im trying to implement laravel websockets and trying to access dashboard.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets Address leads me to the dashboard on my local machine but when i host it and try [www.mysite.com/laravel-websockets](http://www.mysite.com/laravel-websockets), it shows that the page doesn't exist.
Im using [this](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) package for laravel websockets and AWS EC2 Instance for hosting.

**broadcasting.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, access to the WebSocket dashboard is only allowed while your application environment is set to local.

However, you can change this behavior by overriding the Laravel Gate being used. A good place for this is the AuthServiceProvider that ships with Laravel.

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('viewWebSocketsDashboard', function ($user = null) {
            return in_array($user->email, [
               //
            ]);
        });
    }
```

Refer to this doc https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/debugging/dashboard#protecting-the-dashboard